# Where does website like this store its Google Maps marker details?

Tags: google-maps

I've noticed that some websites don't really expose the Maps details (longitude, latitude) in the source. I wonder what practice do they use. I tried to look at the source code, but still couldn't find where the code lies.

Here's an example:

https://squareup.com/retail/search/10001

Do they use external JSON file or what? I still couldn't find though.

Reason I am asking because I will have maps that show multiple markers too, but having them listed in the source is a little messy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the request on page load with something like Firebug (or any inspector), you'll see a URL like this: https://squareup.com/retail?lat=40.75368539999999&lng=-73.9991637 that is an Ajax request that returns a JSON response object.

So, that means that there is a server-side script that is being used to retrieve a set of marker data - probably read from a database.

Comment: More flexibility than performance.  If they want to change the markers they are showing all they will need to do is tweak their database query and nothing in the front end client-side code will need to change.

Comment: This is a few years old but it was an invaluable reference when I was first learning to work with the Google Maps API: http://amzn.com/1590597079